# How to route specific URL segments to separate web root directories?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, yii

My yii project has following structure:

```
webapp  
----frontend  
--------www  
------------index.php
----backend  
--------www  
------------index.php  
----api  
--------www  
------------index.php
```

https://github.com/tonydspaniard/yiinitializr-advanced

Apache 2.2

Each www directory has own .htaccess file. For example "webapp/frontend/www/.htaccess":

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([^/].*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

For separate parts of application i use subdomains "api.webapp.com","admin.webapp.com" (symlinks in public_html folder):

```
webapp.com -> webapp/frontend/www   
api.webapp.com -> webapp/api/www  
admin.webapp.com -> webapp/backend/www
```

But i have problems with cross domain ajax requests to api, and i want to get something like this:

```
http://webapp.com -> webapp/frontend/www/index.php  
http://webapp.com/api/ -> webapp/api/www/index.php   
http://webapp.com/admin/ -> webapp/backend/www/index.php
```

What is the right way to route URL segment to specific web root directory? Aliases, .htaccess, symlinks, maybe something else?

Comment: .htaccess and more then one index.php file works best for pointing entire uri segments to sub folders.

Answer (score 1):

As aCodeSmith said, you can properly configure `.htaccess` file to solve the issue.

1. The document root of `http://webapp.com` should be `webapp`.
2. Right in the document root you should create `.htaccess` file with route rules like that.

```
RewriteCond $1 ^api\/
RewriteRule ^(.*) api/www/index.php [L,PT]

RewriteCond $1 ^admin\/
RewriteRule ^(.*) admin/www/index.php [L,PT]

RewriteRule . frontend/www/index.php
```

Hope, it will help.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, guys.
Now i have two working solutions:
1) by Alex Akr
 webapp is root
webapp/.htaccess:

```
RewriteCond $1 ^api\/
RewriteRule ^(.*) api/www/index.php [L,PT]

RewriteCond $1 ^admin\/
RewriteRule ^(.*) admin/www/index.php [L,PT]

RewriteRule . frontend/www/index.php
```

2) webapp/frontend/www is root.
In apache config set aliases:

```
Alias /api /var/www/webapp/data/www/webapp/api/www
<Directory /var/www/webapp/data/www/webapp/api/www>
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

In /webapp/api/www/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule ^([^/].*)$ /api/index.php/$1 [L]
```